# Commercial use of Google API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, picasa, google-reader, google-cloud-billing, commercial-application

This question maybe a better fit on [The Business of Software forum](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/?biz) but despite my [post on there](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?biz.5.765503.2), I'm still unable to determine the following: Can I use the Google API to build commercial software? If not how can the people behind [Byline](http://www.phantomfish.com/byline.html) charge for their app?

Update: I'm specifically interested in Google's Picasa & Reader APIs

Comment: Google reader don't have public API.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a law/legality question, not a programming one. Questions about law can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com instead (including programming licensing questions).

Comment: Picasa and Reader services were retired a long time ago. Nowadays Google allows developers to integrate many of their APIs into their commercial solutions... just they have to properly set the billing details, some APIs might require a prior verification / approval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Google Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS):

> 5.3 You agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google, **unless you have been specifically allowed to do so in a separate agreement with Google**. You specifically agree not to access (or attempt to access) any of the Services through any automated means (including use of scripts or web crawlers) and shall ensure that you comply with the instructions set out in any robots.txt file present on the Services.

(emphasis added)

More specifically, when you say "the Google API", which of [the many APIs Google exposes](http://code.google.com/more) are you referring to? Each of them has different terms of use. Some can be used commercially, some can't.

Update:

from the [terms](http://code.google.com/apis/picasa/terms.html) for the [Picasa Button and Uploader APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/picasa/)

> 7.1 Subject to the Terms, **you may develop, display and/or distribute your Button using the Services as part of a commercial** or non-commercial enterprise, and you may develop your Button for use in accessing paid content or services.  You **may not charge a separate fee for use of any Button, unless you have entered into a separate signed agreement** with Google.  If you wish to sell or transfer your Button, you must obtain Google’s prior written permission.

from the [terms](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/terms.html) for the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/)

> 5.8 You may use the Picasa Web Albums API as part of a commercial or non-commercial enterprise, subject to these Terms. You may not however charge a separate fee for use of the Picasa Web Albums API unless you have entered into a separate signed agreement with Google.

As far as the [Google Reader API](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=google+reader+api) is concerned, it still appears to be unreleased and so no specific terms are available.

To enter into a signed agreement with Google, you're probably best off [contacting your local Google office](http://www.google.com/intl/en/corporate/address.html) and talking to one of their business development representatives there... Alternatively, you could try contacting the [Business Proposals](http://www.google.com/intl/en/contact/) department from their contact page...

Comment: @Stobor: Picasa & Reader API (see update above). 

How does one go "in a separate agreement with google"? I've read this before and most of their "Terms of Service" state the same thing but no additional information on how to get a separate agreement is provided.

Comment: Thanks @Stobor! How is using the Picasa Web Album API in a commercial enterprise different from charging for a separate free for using the API?

Comment: I think I found the answer to the question of difference between commercial enterprise and separate fee here: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=205433

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Google Web Toolkit:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_GettingStarted.html#Can_I_use_GWT_to_develop_commercial/enterprise_applications?

The answer is Yes.

Comment: GWT seems to be Java based only? What would C# or Objective-C developer use?

Comment: C# users would use Script# (written by a Microsoft employee) http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/.

Comment: Objective-C users would probably use Cappuccino (but they'd be using Objective-J rather than Objective-C).

Answer (score 1):

Which API do you want to use?
I think that Google Maps API has some limitations.
You should read the term of use carefully and make sure that it fits what you want to do.

Update: The Picassa API can be used in a commercial app but you can not charge the user for a separate fee. see 5.8 at http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/picasaweb/terms.html